# How many created graphics in a php file are allowed?

Tags: php, html, image

While I am following the instructions for [generating images](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php) I asked myself:

How many different images can I create in a `php` file, that will be referenced in a `HTML` file like `<img src="images.php" alt"description">`?

I have tried in `images.php` file

```
header(Content-type: image/png);
imagepng($img1);
imagepng($img2);
imagedestroy($img1);
imagedestroy($img2);
```

whitout success. only one image will be displayed.

For that, is it possible to reference an array in `src`?

Or do I need to put every single created image in a single `php` file?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Think the part you are missing is... `\images.php?img=header`, `\images.php?img=fooImg`, etc. Use parameters, don't create essentially the same file over and over. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

No you can't pass an array as a `src`. Make the PHP script take parameters.

Here is the same script, taking a size parameter. You could easily also be passing something like a user ID or image ID. Then your one script becomes capable of serving requested images on demand. This is a common pattern with tracking pixels for use in things like recording email opens.

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-42t7l9U95R4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAc/KvJidye2yro/photo.jpg?sz=24

[image]

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-42t7l9U95R4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAc/KvJidye2yro/photo.jpg?sz=128

[image]